# Extract Form Value PHP with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

I have get html page from other site using `file_get_contents` and i want to extract form value.Html is look like this:

`<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='here'>`

So,how i get `here` using `preg_replace`

What i was tried so far:

`preg_match_all("/'hidden' value='(.*?)'/",$html, $matches);`
Doesn't not work!

Comment: This would be much easier with a `DOM` parser **and** an xpath query: `//input[@name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']`.

Comment: are there some other values which should be also extracted within the content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regexes for parsing HTML. Use tools that are designed specifically for this.

```
$previous_value = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

$string ="<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='here'>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$input = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input')->item(0);
echo $input->getAttribute("value");

libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($previous_value);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/619061)

Comment: Maybe two secs earlier :)

Comment: I like that we two similar but different approaches :)

Comment: Sorry,but not only one form in my string,please update it :(

Comment: @JaparS I'm not here to write your code for you. I just showed you how to do what you need. Now you need to *learn* from this and then use that new knowledge to write your own code to get the values you need.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, use a `DOM` parser instead:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='here'>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$input = $xpath->query("//input[@name = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken']/@value")->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $input;
# here
?>
```

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag section invalid in Entity, line: 66 

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag footer invalid in Entity, line: 82 

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: footer and div in Entity, line: 116 

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in